# How to find the application.properties in spring web app, while location is mentioned as classpath:/application.properties but file is missing?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

This project was not touched for 2 years. Following code is written in spring-security.xml

```
  <b:bean id="mappings" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <b:property name="location">
            <b:value>classpath:/application.properties</b:value>
        </b:property>
  </b:bean> 
  <b:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <b:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
        <b:property name="url" value="${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}" />
        <b:property name="username" value="${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}" />
        <b:property name="password" value="${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}" />
  </b:bean>
```

I checked 
`src/main/resources`, 
entire code base, 
entire system (macOS level search) and I couldn't find application.properties.

What I know for sure is, when the application is run locally(in my laptop) it uses `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` to connect to remote AWS db.

Question: How can I debug and find out the location of the file?

PS: I did try file search etc. for search string 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL'

Comment: May be it is kept in the server where the web app is deployed?

Comment: the webapp is run in my local macbook.

Comment: Hmm, then probably in some jar lib? You can try enabling debug logs for Spring.

Comment: @Smile - You are awesome. It was within Apache tomcat directory. Not sure why it didn't show up in spotlight mac level search though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to answer.

Possibly the property file is in the server folder where the web app is deployed. Further investigation can be done by enabling Spring debug logs.

Comment: ok, my local machine is now fixed. Since I don't have application.properties within the project or WAR, the file has to be there somewhere in apache of ubuntu in Ec2. I checked all apache directory and I couldn't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Search for setenv.sh in tomcat. It should have all the folders which are on classpath and probably in one of the folders, property file should be present.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I debug and find out the location of the file?

Set breakpoints in all public methods of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and its parent classes.